# Bind keys to functions in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, and save it in a file

Tags: macos, vba, ms-word

I am an EMACS user who has to use Microsoft Word a lot. I typically spend 15 minutes binding ^a to beginning-of-line, ^f to next-char, etc. I'm not sure where these keybindings get saved, perhaps in my personal template? I would like to be able to easily move it to another computer.

A while ago it looked like this was saved in a file called Normal.dot. Sometimes when I moved Normal.dot to another computer the keybindings moved along, but other times they didn't. I couldn't figure out why or why not.

It seems to me that the "right" way to do this would be by saving it in a macro and loading that macro into each computer that I use. Surely there is an easy way to do it. I just don't know how.

Can somebody give me the steps? Programs like Microsoft Word used to come with thick manuals, but they don't anymore, and I'm not really sure where to start. I also recall that VBA wasn't supported on MacOS, but now it seems that it is.

Comment: Do you want to append  "^a" before begining of each line? and "^f" to the second character in a word document? Am i right ?

Comment: Is this Mac-Word or Word for Windows? There's a big difference and your question needs to be tagged correctly or you won't reach the right people. If it's Mac-Word you also need to include the version number as VBA support varies greatly between versions!

Comment: Hi, @CindyMeister. This is Mac. I'll update the question. But why do they use different versions of VBA?  I'm using Mac Version 15.16 and Mac version 14.5.8, but the 14.5.8 doesn't seem to work since installing Version 15.

Comment: And, Actually, I really wanted a solution that worked for both Mac and Windows versions. Isn't Word cross-platform?

Comment: Theory and reality are two different things: your question needs to target Mac folks. I've changed the tag to reflect this.